# Font styling not working on smart phone?

Tags: css, mobile, fonts

http://granthoneymoon.com/temp.html is the sample page I'm working on.

Any idea why the font styling is not working on my smart phone? It works everywhere else I've tried. But neither bold nor italics work when I look at it on my galaxy 3.

I'm just using font-style and font-weight.

Comment: Works when emulating a Galaxy S3, could it be something with your specific device?

Comment: Make sure you leverage a google font, it should be reliable unless this is a device specific issue with the font you're using

Comment: Please note that [the "phone" tag is discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/phone/info) because it does not indicate *which kind* of phone you're using; I'm assuming that this is Android? Please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here and tell us **which browser** are you using.

Answer (score 0):

Appearantly, this is somewhat of a known issue with the Samsung S3 devices. [There's even a chromium issue regarding it.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=169446)

You could try visiting [the android text test website](https://sites.google.com/site/chrometexttest/) on your device and see if it displays the font stylings correctly. If it is you should be able to fix your problem by changing the font(s) of the website.